# Get top max item by linq

Tags: c#, linq

consider:

```
public class student
{
public int Avd{get;set;}
}
```

and in main :

```
list<student> Students =new List<student>{2,3,6,1,20,12,45};
```

I want get top 5  max  AVG in Students by linq  . how can i do this?

Comment: This code doesn't even compile. Also do you mean top 5 max Avd rather than AVG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Students = Students.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Avd).Take(5).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the list based on `Avg` in *descending* order then use `Take` to get 5 students:

```
Students.OrderByDescending(s => s.Avg).Take(5);
```